# Kotlin Coroutine transaction in Reactive SQL Client (Quarkus/Vert.X)

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, vert.x, quarkus, mutiny

I want to use Kotlin coroutines in my reactive sql client transactions.
For simplicity, I was going to use the provided helper function `io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Pool#withTransaction`  mentioned in the docs [here](https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-sql-clients#transactions). Since the passed function is not a coroutine suspend function, I'm getting an error like `Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body` when Im trying to compile a code like the following

```
val client : PgPool
... 

suspend fun someServiceFunction () {
    client.withTransaction { connection ->
        repository.save(connection, entity).awaitSuspending()   //This is not working
        ...
    }
}
```

The function header for the withTransaction looks like this

```
@CheckReturnValue
public <T> Uni<T> withTransaction(Function<SqlConnection, Uni<T>> function)
```

I'm asking myself if there is still a way to use this with kotlin coroutines, since I'm pretty new to them.

Thank you for any help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Mutiny nor Quarkus, but it seems there is a way to convert from `Deferred<T>` to `Uni<T>` in `mutiny-kotlin`, which you seem to be using.

You could therefore create your own suspending version of `withTransaction` like this:

```kotlin
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.SqlConnection
import io.vertx.mutiny.sqlclient.Pool

@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
suspend fun <T> Pool.withTransaction(block: suspend (SqlConnection) -> T): T = coroutineScope {
    client.withTransaction { connection ->
        async { block(connection) }.asUni()
    }.awaitSuspending()
}
```

And then use it:

```kotlin
suspend fun someServiceFunction() {
    client.withTransaction { connection ->
        repository.save(connection, entity).awaitSuspending()
        // potentially other suspending stuff here, without the need to combine()
    }
}
```

But that begs the question, why use the Mutiny variant of Vertx things, if in the end you want to use Kotlin coroutines? I think by default Vertx works with Java futures which are also integrated with coroutines.

Comment: Thank you very much ! So using the raw vertx client sounds feasable. Though what do you exactly mean with `Java futures which are also integrated with coroutines` ? Would it be easily portable ? Would love to see an example

Comment: @AhmetKazaman I'm sorry I'm not very knowledgeable about this ecosystem, but it looks like the mutiny-based clients are already adapted on top of vertx "pure" clients, that's I was thinking that it looks like we're stacking adapter layers here. But nothing critical I guess.